# implement @else @endif in PHP for html

Tags: php, html, laravel

I see in a *laravel* project which there is some **@if**, **@else** and **@endif** inside html code and that was really readable. Is it possible to implement them for my PHP project to replace with PHP codes like `<?php } else { ?>` or `<?php }?>`.

I don't wanna use Laravel for my project.

Comment: Laravel is using blade, blade is using this syntax, and not PHP. But you could do something like this : https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Meaning no, you can't do this in pure PHP, because it's a question of syntax.

Comment: PHP creator, Rasmus Lerdorf, once said in a conference I saw in YouTube something like "people are using my template engine to write template engines" 

Answer (score 1):

You can if you use a [template engine](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/847/top-7-best-open-source-php-template-engines). If you are happy with Blade you can use it without use Laravel.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer imh.

Comment: I know but the question was "Is it possible to implement them for my PHP project" and what I've written does answer it, regardless the unlike xD.

Comment: Just because a question is answerble doesn't mean we should answer it ;) Or we'd be encouraging bad questions to exist